# Can not copy and paste umlauts from PDF

Tags: pdftex, pdf, ligatures

I got a text that is written in German. I'm using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` since the text comes with the correct `umlauts` like ö, ä, ü and not "o, "a, "u. The output is pretty fine.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  

%\input{glyphtounicode}
%\pdfgentounicode=1

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}
Viele Menschen sollten denken können, aber möchten es nicht. Dies ist ein Text den ich im PDF sehen möchte.
\end{document}
```

But when I'm trying to copy text from the output (PDF) to Word, then I get the following:

> Viele Menschen sollten denken k¨onnen, aber m¨ochten es nicht. Dies
>   ist ein Text den ich im PDF sehen m¨ochte.

**Question:** Any workaround here? The PDF text must support Copy&Paste. The glyphtounicode didn't help. Any idea?

Comment: Try to add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` or `\usepackage{lmodern}` since Computer Modern doesn't have pre-composed accented characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it. I just had to add another line `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.